# Processing data while it is loading

Tags: optimization

We have a tool which loads data from some optical media, and once it's all copied to the hard drive runs it through a third-party tool for processing. I would like to optimise this process so each file is processed as it is read in. Trouble is, the third-party tool (which naturally I cannot change) has a 12 second startup overhead. What is the best way I can deal with this, in terms of finishing the entire process as soon as possible? I can pass any number of files to the processing tool in each run, so I need to be able to determine exactly when to run the tool to get the fastest result overall. The data being copied could be anything from one large file (which can't be processed until it's fully copied) to hundreds of small files.

Comment: What is the system you are running it on? Can you concatenate the files before feeding the third party tool?

Comment: Windows 7 x64. I don't really see how concatenating the files would help? That would mean I would have to wait for all the files to copy before I could start, so I wouldn't achieve anything. The 12s overhead is per run, not per file, so it's not much of an issue when all the files are processed in one batch after all the files are copied; it's only a problem when I am running it several times.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to create and run 2 threads, one that runs the tool and one that loads data. Start 12 seconds timer and trigger both threads. Upon each file load completion check the passed time. If 12 seconds passed, fetch the data into the thread running the tool. Restart loading the data in parallel to processing of previous bulk. Once previous bulk processing completes restart the 12 sec timer and continue checking it upon every file load completion. Repeat till no more data remains.

For better results a more complex solution might be required. You can do some benchmarking to get an evaluation of average data loading time. Since it might be different for small and large files, several evaluations may be needed for different categories of files (according to size). Optimal resources utilization would be the one that processes the data in the same rate the new data arrives. Processing time includes the 12 seconds startup. The benchmarking should give you a ratio of processing threads number vs. reading threads number (you can also decrease/increase the number of active reading threads according to the incoming file sizes). Actually, it's a variation of [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem with multiple producers and consumers.